# Can not make vertical-align:middle work in a bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

**Update**

Based on jme11 answer the d-flex is preventing the alignment, however without d-flex the columns are totally messed up (using bootstrap 4)
To reporoduce:  (first row should be aligned middle, but it is not)

http://jsbin.com/fafoweleka/1/edit?html,css,output

**Context**

I would like to align my text in a bootstrap 4 table. I am trying to use `vertical-align:middle`, but text is still aligned to top.

**Question**

What am I missing?

Markup:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr class="d-flex">
    <td class="col-1">1</td>
    <td class="col-4" style="vertical-align:middle">Miami</td>
    <td class="col-3">4.0</td>
    <td class="col-3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a little more context? Because on jsbin, i'm trying to reproduce your case and it's in middle by default...  https://jsbin.com/tutofowuvu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's my problem too. I am using minton theme from wrapbootstrap, so the context is really big... but nothing else fancy. (bootstrap 4). I am also newbie in html/css so any idea how can I diagnose what is interfering helps. (I am using Chrome dev tools.)

Comment: well, seeing where to goes this, I do not think it is so bad question. I am sure many developer will trapped with d-flex or not d-flex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT

If you want to use the d-flex class on the tr elements to allow for use of the col classes on the cells, you can align the text in a specific cell vertically by adding d-flex and align-items-center class to that cell.

```css
.strecher {
   height: 200px;
 }
 
 .my-table td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <h3>For a specific cell:</h3>
  <table class="table" style="background-color: #eee;">
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-1">1</td>
      <td class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center">Miami</td>
      <td class="col-3">4.0</td>
      <td class="col-3"><div class=strecher></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <h3>For all cells:</h3>
  <table class="table my-table" style="background-color: #eee;">
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-1">1</td>
      <td class="col-4">Miami</td>
      <td class="col-3">4.0</td>
      <td class="col-3"><div class=strecher></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should not the inline style in my sample overrule the bootstrap style?

Comment: It totally would, except in your jsBin, the class for display flex was applied and there were some other conflicting styles issues because you didn't apply the table class.  Here's a working version of your jsBin with the inline style: http://jsbin.com/dugulivona/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4 so I changed the links in the sample. You are right the d-flex is preventing the alignment, however without d-flex the columns are totally messed up. http://jsbin.com/fafoweleka/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Many thanks. It seems this d-flex thing needs more attention (and learning)